# Prove equation with Taylor, change of variable and Hopital

Tags: real-analysis

If $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$  such that,
$$f(0)=1, \quad f'(0) =0,$$

and $$f''(0) = -1,$$

then $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}$ we have

$$\lim _{x\to +\infty} \left( f(\frac{a}{\sqrt{x}}) \right)^x = e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}.$$

Is that true? And how I can prove that using taylor, a change of variable and Hopital?

Answer (score 1):

By using a Taylor series expansion, as $x \to \infty$, one has
$$
f\Big(\frac{a}{\sqrt{x}}\Big) =f(0)+\frac{a}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot f'(0)+\frac{a^2}{x}\cdot \frac{f''(0)}{2!}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac1{x^{3/2}} \right)
$$ that is
$$
f\Big(\frac{a}{\sqrt{x}}\Big) =1-\frac{a^2}{2x}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac1{x^{3/2}} \right)
$$ giving, as $x \to \infty$,

> $$
> \left(f\Big(\frac{a}{\sqrt{x}}\Big)\right)^x=e^{x \log \left(1-\frac{a^2}{2x}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac1{x^{3/2}} \right) \right)}=e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\right)} \to e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}},
> $$

since $\log(1-u)=-u+O(u^2)$ as $u \to 0.$

Comment: Can also be solved with a change of variable? like for example, 1/x=t?

Comment: @Mr.Dot Yes, this was implicitly done.

Comment: ok, one last thing: why did you write o(1/x^(3/2))?? it's for Taylor of 3rd order. If i'm not wrong, it should be o(1/x) because of the 2nd order. Tell me if I made a mistake.

Comment: It is rather the *third* other of the variable $a/\sqrt{x}$ giving, on line 1, $O(1/x^{3/2})$.